# Closure advanced compression with external libraries: Backbone.js, underscore.js

Tags: backbone.js, google-closure-compiler

General help needed for using Closure's advanced compression when my scripts depend on Backbone.js and Underscore.js.

I've tried reading through Closure's API tutorial, but couldn't get my compiled scripts working. Specifically I added a js_externs parameter:

```
('js_externs', 'function _(){};function Backbone(){}')
```

into my python script (a la http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#howto-app) but this hasn't worked.

Comment: You need to ask a question here or there's not really much we can do to help you.

Comment: Many JS libraries are not written to follow the strict restrictions mandated by the Closure compiler in advanced mode.  Therefore you either have to build a comprehensive "externs" file for it (not an easy task), or modify it to make it compliant (again not easy).  It is very difficult to use Closure Advanced mode with third-party libraries.

Comment: If you want to modify the libraries yourself, check out this doc: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf -- it should give you some hints on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need more in your externs that simply the variable declarations, in advanced mode you also need the properties defined by the backbone library that you are using or you need to use quoted properties access (an array access) for every property:

```
_['aBackboneMethod']()
```

For example here is the jQuery externs file:

http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/search?q=jquery-1.7.js&origq=jquery-1.7.js&btnG=Search+Trunk

Answer (score -3):

I just had a need for similar setup. You don't need to *extern* Backbone. Just drop uncompressed backbone.js, underscore.js, jquery.js on your path (plovr anyone?), put `goog.provide('Backbone')`, `goog.provide('underscore')`, `goog.provide('jQuery')` on top of those files, then `goog.require('Backbone')` wherever you need it. Voilà!

Comment: Unless those scripts are known to be compatible with Closure-compiler using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS (jQuery for sure isn't), this isn't going to work.

Comment: That indeed doesn't work, although one would expect this to be the idiomatic approach to 'closurify' external JS.